# tkinter button overlaying labels

Tags: python, tkinter

I am completely new to using tkinter and I have stumbled upon a issue, when trying to setup my calculator GUI the button keeps overlaying the labels (Just trying to get the general UI down before actually setting it up)

What am I doing wrong that causes it to do this? Maybe some advice or tutorials I can look at. Thanks.

```
from tkinter import *

calc = Tk()
calc.title("Calculator")
calc.geometry("200x150")

app = Frame(calc)
app.grid()

add = Label(text="Addition").grid(row=0, column=0)
sub = Label(text="Subtraction").grid(row=1,column=0)
mul = Label(text="Multiplication").grid(row=0, column=1)
div = Label(text="Division").grid(row=1, column=1)
submit = Button(app, text="CALCULATE").grid(row=2, column=0)


calc.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The labels and the button should have the same parent.

Make these changes:

```
add = Label(app, text="Addition").grid(row=0, column=0)
sub = Label(app, text="Subtraction").grid(row=1,column=0)
mul = Label(app, text="Multiplication").grid(row=0, column=1)
div = Label(app, text="Division").grid(row=1, column=1)
```

Comment: It's not quite true to say the _should_ have the same parent. That's possibly the right solution, but not the only solution.